# My bootstrap(card-deck) is not applied when I open it in browser

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, web-development-server

I am designing a website but when i tried to wrote code for bootstrap(card-deck class) in codeply.com it was
working properly. But when i wrote the same code in my Py charm code editor and paste the file link in my browser at that time my code wasn't applied..

Can anyone guide me why it is happening??

Here is my code

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>Free</h2>
      <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
      <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Labrador</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
      <p>Pirority Listing</p>
      <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
      <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
      <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for.. but I think the issue is the Bootstrap Version you are running the code on.

I had just about the same issue running a particular line of code that runs well while on Bootstrap version 4.0 but seem not to work at all while running on bootstrap Version 5.1.  Turns out the bootstrap changed a particular class attribute from what it used to be in version 4.

Example:
Bootstrap 5 uses class=(data-bs-) instead of its previous class=(data-) attributes in bootstrap 4.

With that little change as seen above, your line of code won't work.. rather the class name used, need to be in the exact way it was written in the bootstrap version you are using.